# Java onCreate with parameter like in initWithParameter c++

Tags: java, android, initialization, oncreate

may be its too simple but I couldnt find the right way.

In C++ I can write `initWithParameter: xxx` to instantiate a class and then in the init set some instance variables given the value at init time.

In Java I don't know how to do that. Currently I do the following:

```
public class SpecialScreen extends BASEScreen{
private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //create the instance
    defineScreenType (ACTIVITY_1); //second call to set the instance variable
    presentOnScreen();
}
```

While in BASEScreen:

```
public class BASEScreen extends Activity {
private Integer activityCode; // which activity should I do?

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  // the creation
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

// the setting of the instance variable
public void defineScreenType(int screenID) {
    activityCode = screenID;

}
```

This can't be the best way of doing it. How to do this better?

Thanks

ADDED to show the calling of the SpecialScreen within BASEScreen:

```
    @Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    Intent i;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case OTHER_PAGE_ID:
        // 
        if (activityCode == ACTIVITY_1) {
            i = new Intent(this, SpecialScreen2.class);
            i.putExtra("Task", ACTIVITY_2);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_2);
            finish();

        } else {
            i = new Intent(this, SpecialScreen1.class);
            i.putExtra("Task", ACTIVITY_1);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_1);
            finish();
        }

        return true;
```

ps I know that putting the Extra is not required anymore. This was the way I did it before I had the two SpecialScreen subclasses and always called the BASEScreen with this parameter.

Comment: Retagged as an android question, as that's what it appears to be.

Comment: @user387184: What are you trying to do? Something like 'user presses button 1, start activity 1', 'user presses button 2, start activity 2'? Starting different activities based on user choice or some other condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, there is no "default" syntax like in c++. You have to do it in the constructor. Mind you, you don't need to use the setter method, you could make `activityCode` protected rather than private, and just do:

```
activityCode = ACTIVITY_1;
```

The other option is using the Builder Pattern to construct your objects, using a set of defaults inside the builder that you override (when needed) when requesting the object be built.

**Edit in response to comments below:**

I apologize for some confusion as I was calling it a "constructor" when it's not.

If in `BASEScreen` you change the access to `protected` from `private`

```
public class BASEScreen extends Activity {
    protected Integer activityCode;
```

You can then access that in the `SpecialScreen` subclass:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activityCode = 1; // Or ACTIVITY_1 if you'd like
    presentOnScreen();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, also here I am not sure In understand fully. Where do I set the activityCode? I have to do it inside the BASEScreen right? So I should pass it somehow like John Munsch wrote above? Please explain... Thanks

Comment: Sorry, see my edit above. I wasn't paying enough attention to your example code as you aren't calling a constructor directly.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question properly. Any class in Java can have one or more constructors. Each one can have either no parameters or some set of parameters you pass in (although they have to each have a unique set/order so the compiler can tell which one you intend to use).

```
public class SpecialScreen extends BASEScreen {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_1 = 1;

    // There is a default constructor with no parameters provided for you
    // by default if you don't define any constructors.
    public SpecialScreen() {
       // I'm overriding the default constructor and this one will do 
       // something else.
       super(ACTIVITY_1);
    }

    // But you can also have ones like this.
    public SpecialScreen(int activity) {
       super(activity);
    }
}
```

Each is invoked when you perform a new, for example:

BASEScreen porcupine = new SpecialScreen(); // No parameter constructor.

or

BASEScreen porcupine = new SpecialScreen(5); // Constructor that takes the parameter.

Comment: Sorry, dont really get it. Where is my activityCode variable set for the created object? The created object needs to know which kind of screen it actually is - what am I missing here?